# A Twisty Puzzle my friend barely remembers

Tags: puzzle-identification, twisty-puzzles

I was impressing various students at my school by showing them various twisty puzzles when one of them recalled a puzzle they owned. I thought I might have seen it somewhere, but I may have been thinking about something else.

He said it had some sort of gear mechanism, and was a two-by-two cube. But one of the key features of this cube was this: you could pull it apart on one of the axes, and turn the parts separately.

I showed him the Skewb shift, the only puzzle I was aware pulled apart, but he said that wasn't it. Exactly one axis pulled apart, and also, it was two by two.

Anyone know what cube this could be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called **Gear Shift**:
[image]

It was invented by [Oskar van Deventer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oskar_van_Deventer), and produced by Meffert.

The Skewb Shift was a later design inspired by this one.

Note however that the Gear shift can pull apart along all 3 axes (but only one at a time).

Comment: I was just about to write an answer, but you beat me to it. ;) +1

Comment: @Kevin Avatar checks out.

Comment: @Randal'Thor From me or Jaap (both I guess :) )?